# Org Browser - Multiple Managers

Tags: organization-browser

We have multiple managers - so the AD contsraint of only being able to assign one manager to an AD user object is causing a problem.

We'd like to use the silverlight Orginazation Browser if possible though, so I'm working through how I'd make this fit our needs:

1. I'm thinking I could add a few custom fields in AD to hold the multiple managers
2. Associate that with some new custom fields in User Profile Sync
3. But then I don't know how we could get in and modify the Org Browser...

Any thoughts?

And yes, I know there's a third party tool to create your own org charts based on lists... I'm just trying to get the slick silverlight component to work for our org.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt if the Org Browser supports what you're trying to do.

The component is built for a specific function and that is 1 manager per person.

Your best bet, would be to get a developer to build a custom Silverlight Control which can handle your companies' manager logic.

Sorry, but that's all I can offer.

Comment: Also consider that you might break Colleagues, Team Manager, Team, Social Distance, and other SharePoint specific functions that require manager to be there as a single person